# Recommend tag merger: equity - equitable-relief

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I recommend we merge [equity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equity) and [equitable-relief](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equitable-relief), or in the alternative, give each of them some usage guidance to distinguish where each is appropriate.

See "[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work):

> In some cases, tags that are subsets of other tags will also be considered synonyms, such as java-se for java.

Answer (score 1):

This looks reasonable to me. we don't hsve many questions that really fit under [equitable-relief](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equitable-relief), perhaps it should be a synonym.

I gather someone disapproves of this proposal. It would be helpful if that person explained why.

Answer (score 1):

### Again, not synonyms

Equity has to do with the law of equity. Equitable relief is *one* of the remedies under the law (equity or common law).

Comment: That's not how it works, Jen. I can get an injunction under equity law, but that's not equitable-relief.

Comment: @Trish an injunction is always equitable relief even if it is not issued for an equitable cause of action.